# XML Configuration to Java Configuration - Spring Security in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, spring-security

I'm working on a spring to springboot conversion project. In the existing spring project, I have below secure.xml file which needs to be converted into Java Configuration Class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
   <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/login">
    <csrf disabled="true" />  
   </http>
   <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/abc/la/**">
    <csrf disabled="true" />  
   </http>
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/abc/**"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />   
        <intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager
        alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider
            ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.foo.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />
    <beans:bean id="encoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength"
            value="6" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

I have converted above xml config to below Java config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers("/login").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN","USER");
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers("/abc/la/**").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN","USER");
        
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN","USER")
        .antMatchers("/logout").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN","USER")
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN","USER")
        .antMatchers("/abc/**").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN","USER")
        .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password");
        
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout");;
        
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(6);
    }

     }
```

Problem is that I'm not able to access "/login" url. It says **You don't have authorization to view this page.**
[image]
But if I replace the following

```
.antMatchers("/login").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN","USER")
.antMatchers("/logout").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN","USER")
.antMatchers("/resources/**").hasAnyRole("ANONYMOUS","ADMIN","USER")
```

with

```
.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
```

then it is loading the login page. Is there anything wrong in my JavaConfig class or Am I missing something? Why my existing spring app is working with "hasAnyRole("ROLE_ANONYMOUS","ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER")" but not in Springboot?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: docs for `hasAnyRole` reads the following: `Shortcut for specifying URLs require any of a number of roles. If you do not want to have "ROLE_" automatically inserted see hasAnyAuthority(String) Parameters: roles the roles to require (i.e. USER, ADMIN, etc). Note, it should not start with "ROLE_" as this is automatically inserted.`

Comment: My point is that "ROLE_" is working in the existing spring application but not in springboot app. I'm getting **access denied** error for **/login** page.

Comment: My point is, that you are not reading the docs... That is because `access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')"` is evaluated by `SecurityExpressionRoot` which checks for the `ROLE_` prefix and if present does not prepend it. When using `hasAnyRole` method, the `ROLE_` prefix is always prepended, thus having you end up with `ROLE_ROLE_ANONYMOUS`, `ROLE_ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_ROLE_USER`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, Thanks for quick response. But even after removing the "ROLE_" from hasAnyRole() method, I'm still getting the **"Access Denied"** error when I hit the **"/login"** page

Comment: That is probably because the user has no role before logging in. If you want to allow anonymous users to access a page, use `anonymous()` method